# Which one should I choose for simple task: async/await or promise.then?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, axios

I made a helper function for drawing the `map(OpenLayers)`.
Then I made another helper function for `fetch(axios.get)` the map URL.

So my question is should I switch from

- from `.then()` (`loadMap_before()`)
- to `async/await`  (`loadMap()`)  ?

Which way is better?

Or option3 is the best where `loadMapUrl()` helper is totally unnecessary?

Is there any other place where I can improve my code?

#### Option #1 with `promise.then`

```
export const loadMapUrl_before =  (storeMapUrl, storeMapExtent) => {
  let result = {}
  if (!storeMapUrl) {
     getNaviMap().then(res => {
    result.mapExtent = [res.data.origin_x, res.data.origin_y,
    res.data.width * res.data.resolution + res.data.origin_x,
    res.data.height * res.data.resolution + res.data.origin_y];
    result.mapUrl = res.data.image_url})
.catch(...)
  } else {
    result.mapExtent = storeMapExtent
    result.mapUrl = storeMapUrl
  }
  return result
}
```

#### Option #2 with `async/await`

```
//load map url from store or get it through axios request
export const loadMapUrl = async (storeMapUrl, storeMapExtent) => {
  let result = {}
  if (!storeMapUrl) {
    let res = await getNaviMap()
    result.mapExtent = [res.data.origin_x, res.data.origin_y,
    res.data.width * res.data.resolution + res.data.origin_x,
    res.data.height * res.data.resolution + res.data.origin_y];
    result.mapUrl = res.data.image_url
  } else {
    result.mapExtent = storeMapExtent
    result.mapUrl = storeMapUrl
  }
  return result
}
```

#### Usage

```
// where I call loadMapUrl()
export const loadMap = async (storeMapUrl, storeMapExtent, map, mapLayer) => {
  let mapUrl = '', mapExtent = []
  await loadMapUrl(storeMapUrl, storeMapExtent).then(result => {
    mapUrl = result.mapUrl
    mapExtent = result.mapExtent
  })

  const projection = new Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:4326',
    units: 'degrees',
    extent: mapExtent
  });

  map.setView(new View({
    center: getCenter(mapExtent),
    projection: projection,
    zoom: map.getView().getZoom(),
    minZoom: 0.1,
    maxZoom: 7
  }));

  const source = new Static({
    attributions: 'xxx',
    url: mapUrl,
    projection: projection,
    imageExtent: mapExtent
  });

  mapLayer.setSource(source);
};
```

#### Option #3 the helper for axios request might be redundant

```
export const loadMap = async (storeMapUrl, storeMapExtent, map, mapLayer) => {
  let mapUrl = '', mapExtent = []
 if (!storeMapUrl) {
    let res = await getNaviMap()
    mapExtent = [res.data.origin_x, res.data.origin_y,
    res.data.width * res.data.resolution + res.data.origin_x,
    res.data.height * res.data.resolution + res.data.origin_y];
    mapUrl = res.data.image_url
  } else {
    mapExtent = storeMapExtent
    mapUrl = storeMapUrl
  }
 ...
};
```

Comment: Your `loadMapUrl_before` doesn't seem to be completely working when you don't have a `storeMapUrl` (at least you are returning result which would be only filled by the promise and not before)

Comment: @Icepickle Hi, thanks for the replay, legit concern but you might not be noticed that I used await with loadMapUrl_before, so I think should be fine to return a pending promise

Comment: But, you are not returning a pending promise, you are returning `result` for option1

Comment: @Icepickle  loadMap() can be a regular function without async/await

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: @Mast Thanks a lot for the editing

Comment: No problem. Will you manage to change the title yourself?